# how to draw a polygon in leaflet and add it to geojson file

Tags: leaflet, geojson, editing

I am working on a small project with leaflet. the goal of the project is to show a geojson file and updating it dynamicaly from the window of the web site. I have imported the geojson file to the map. here is the code i used:

```
var geojson;

geojson = L.geoJson(lotData, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
});
```

Now i want to update the geojson file: i want to add a polygon to the file dynamically and to delete an other one from the file. The problem is that i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Is this being served from a server? And you want to update the geojson file on the server from user interaction at the browser? You're going to have to start caring about security and concurrency and stuff. This isn't a small project any more... You might want to look at Django and its spatial GeoDjango extensions on the server side.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question and difficult to answer as the solution will necessarily be complex. In some ways you are describing browser-based GIS.

To get started, perhaps check out the following components:

1. [Leaflet Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw). A great set of easy to use and extendable tools for drawing and editing polygons on screen through a browser.
2. [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/). Using Leaflet Draw callbacks like `draw:created`, you can post polygons to a server running PostGIS; add polygons, intersect, delete, etc., and return geojson.
3. [Turf.js](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf). It may also be possible to do the adding/deleting/saving of polygons in-browser with a library like turf.js. Performance will depend on how large your polygons and geojson files are.